# Uri fails to encode Plus Symbol ('+') when passed as an argument

Tags: flutter, dart, uri

When using [Uri.http()](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/Uri/Uri.http.html) to create a Uri to fetch a data, it fails to encode properly if the string contains a Plus symbol ('+'). But if I hardcode it directly as a String inside the parameter, it successfully encodes the plus symbol as '%2B'.

Here is my code:

```
//widget param is: pA7+pWPaPSZUw5VKimKVlzA3mKrg=
      final getFromUri = Uri.http(
        widget.config,
        'invoiceTracking',
        {'tracking' : widget.param},
    //hardcoding the parameter {'tracking' : 'pA7+pWPaPSZUw5VKimKVlzA3mKrg='},
      );
```

if I encode it this way, it sent it as this:

"pA7+pWPaPSZUw5VKimKVlzA3mKrg%3D"

but if I pass the string directly into the parameter, it successfully encodes it to this:
"pA7%2BpWPaPSZUw5VKimKVlzA3mKrg%3D"

How do I encode the string properly using Uri?

Comment: Please post a complete, minimal example that reproduces the problem you're observing.  If `widget.param` is the `String` `'pA7+pWPaPSZUw5VKimKVlzA3mKrg='`, there should be no difference whether you use `{'tracking' : widget.param}` or `{'tracking' : 'pA7+pWPaPSZUw5VKimKVlzA3mKrg='}`.

Comment: I'm using GoRouter to pass the parameter from the route's queryParams, I think this might be the cause of it, it converted the + symbol to ' ' space before the Uri parses the input.